# Upload file with text boxes (Uploading is optional)

Tags: mysql, file, codeigniter, upload

I have a form in which there are both types of fields means inputs text , radio , select , textarea and file upload fields.
I am using the same form for insert and edit.
My problem is that i have to upload file and insert the data in the table.
Also the uploading is optonal. I have failed to find any logic to handle this. Can anyone suggest how i can do this task?

Comment: Do you mean file upload is required when creating a new record and optional when editing? Maybe you can try breaking down the steps to make it easier to understand.

Comment: no i mean upload is optional either when insert or edate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little research i have found a solution here

Using Codeigniter Form Validation Library

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html

And

http://keighl.com/post/codeigniter-file-upload-validation

A great article. Solver my problem

Answer (score 0):

In semi-pseducode the logic would be

```
 if ($this->form_validation('your_rule'))
   {
         // Insert data to database
     $this->insert('stuff');

     // Now check for file upload
     if ($FILES['file_name'])
     {
        // Do upload
     }
}
```

OR

You can make a custom callback to handle the upload as part of the form_validation. Then include this 'rule' in your form validation - and it will handle everything in the one sweep

Comment: and what if there is a problem in file upload

Comment: then the form validation files - and it returns the user to the form page with the error message, and all the fields filled in. This is really good if you want to restrict the upload - i.e. only upload PDFs

Comment: the problem is quite complex i have three kind of uploads images(multiple) , video and docs